# SQL Syntax error CREATE Table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql, ddl

I get a syntax error when I try to execute this query:

```
USE MainDB1
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE Name = 'logging' AND TYPE = 'u')
BEGIN
DROP TABLE MainDB1.dbo.logging
END
Create Table logging (TIME NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,1-Bit_Boolean NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,1-Bit_Boolean NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,1-Bit_Boolean NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,1-Bit_Boolean NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,64-Bit_IEEE_floating_point NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,64-Bit_IEEE_floating_point NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,64-Bit_IEEE_floating_point NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,64-Bit_IEEE_floating_point NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,64-Bit_IEEE_floating_point_array NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,32-Bit_unsigned_integer NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,32-Bit_unsigned_integer NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,32-Bit_unsigned_integer NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,32-Bit_unsigned_integer NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,32-Bit_unsigned_integer_array NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,32-Bit_IEEE_floating_point NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,32-Bit_IEEE_floating_point NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,32-Bit_IEEE_floating_point NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,32-Bit_IEEE_floating_point NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,32-Bit_IEEE_floating_point_array NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,32-Bit_signed_integer NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,32-Bit_signed_integer NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,32-Bit_signed_integer NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,32-Bit_signed_integer NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,32-Bit_signed_integer_array NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,16-Bit_signed_integer NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,16-Bit_signed_integer NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,16-Bit_signed_integer NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,16-Bit_signed_integer NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,16-Bit_signed_integer_array NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,16-Bit_unsigned_integer NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,16-Bit_unsigned_integer NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,16-Bit_unsigned_integer NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,16-Bit_unsigned_integer NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,16-Bit_unsigned_integer_array NVarChar(20) NOT NULL)
```

The syntax error occurs at the first 1-Bit_Boolean on line 6. The query is saved in a string and later executed.

VB.NET code:

```
    Dim sqlcreatetable As String = _
    "USE MainDB1" & vbCrLf & _
    "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE Name = 'logging' AND TYPE = 'u')" & vbCrLf & _
    "BEGIN" & vbCrLf & _
    "DROP TABLE MainDB1.dbo.logging" & vbCrLf & _
    "END" & vbCrLf & _
    "Create Table logging (TIME NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,"
    For i As Integer = 1 To aantaltags - 1
        If (i = aantaltags - 1) Then
            sqlcreatetable += csvsql(i) & " NVarChar(20) NOT NULL)"
        Else
            sqlcreatetable += csvsql(i) & " NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,"
        End If
    Next

    Dim dbConnection As New SqlCommand(sqlcreatetable, connection)
    connection.Open()
    dbConnection.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connection.Close()
```

Comment: Enclose your column names in brackets: `[1-Bit_Boolean]`

You have much larger problems, though. You're trying to create the same column several times, not using correct data types (why store a boolean in a string type column?), and not using descriptive column names.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2e66i9EB this is the csv that is basis of the column names. There are 4 1-bit booleans. Also the csv is not the one I'll end up using. The descriptions will be clearer but I don't have one that is any more realistic then this one right now. I also won't be storing any booleans, the datatype will be variable but it will probably be mostly 16 or 32 bit integers. They will always be numbers but there might be some floating points. What kind of data type would support these best?

Comment: That code looks like a pain in the aANtALtags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant use number at the starting of the column name and you can't use the "-" anywhere in the column name . you have to write query something like..

```
USE MainDB1 

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE Name = 'logging' AND TYPE = 'u') 
BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE MainDB1.dbo.logging 
END 

Create Table logging  
   (TIME NVarChar(20) NOT NULL, Bit_1_Boolean NVarChar(20) NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. apparently you can but you have to use [ ] around your name for it the work.